# Inconsistent SSL connection error when using wget

Tags: ssl, wget

I'm trying to download some .nc files from a secure online database.

It seems like for roughly every other attempted file download, I get an 'Unable to establish SSL connection' message, and then wget starts (succesfully) downloading the next file.

This is the line I'm using:

> ```
> .\wget.exe --user=username --password=password -r --retry-connrefused
> -e robots=off -np -nH --cut-dirs=7 -R index.html,index.html.tmp -t 0 
> https://address-of-directory
> ```

Is there a way of getting wget to retry each file until it successfully establishes SSL connection - or working around this?

I've tried `--retry-connrefused` command and setting retries to unlimited, but this doesn't seem to work for the SSL connection error.

I've also tried `--no-check-certificate` with the above and the same issue is still there. I'm confused why this error is only appearing for some of the files in the exact same directory? I'm typing these commands into Windows Powershell if that explains anything?